# Deleting current item in object with foreach - CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, foreach

I am using CodeIgniter and want to remove an item from object in a loop

```
foreach($query->result() as $row){
     if($row->parent_id == 1){
         // code here to delete current record
    }
}
```

I want to use foreach to loop all record. In case current item in loop meet condition in if,  delete current row in $query object.

Can I delete current record in $query object in CodeIgniter Or Have others way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

**To Removing an item from object in a loop**

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");
$rows = $query->result();
foreach ($rows as $key => $row)
{
  if($row->parent_id == 1){
      unset($rows[$key]);
     // code here to delete current record
  }
}

print_r($rows) // remove row with parent_id = 1
```

See more @ [Removing an item from object in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843157/removing-an-item-from-object-in-a-loop)

You could also change your select statement to get all records where parent_id not eq 1 (or other 'where' logic to filter the rows... see example and link below)

```
$this->db->get('mytable')
$this->db->where('parent_id !=', 1);
```

or

```
//get all except parent id 1,4 or 7
$parent_ids = array(1, 4, 7);
$this->db->where_not_in('parent_id', $parent_ids);
```

**To delete records from the database as your previous question title suggested (Delete current record with foreach in CodeIgniter)**

You can do this using sql query without using any php logic by write the condition in sql ... see more at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

example

```
//delete record where parent_id = 1
$this->db->delete('mytable', array('parent_id' => 1));
```

or

```
//delete record where parent_id = 1 or 5 or 8
$names = array(1, 5, 8);
$this->db->where_in('parent_id', $names);
$this->db->delete('mytable');
```

or

```
//delete record where parent_id = 1
$this->db->where('parent_id', 1);
$this->db->delete('mytable');
```

or

```
//delete all record where parent_id not eq 1
$this->db->where('parent_id !=', 1);

//delete all record where parent_id less than 10
$this->db->where('parent_id <', 10);
```

Comment: I don't want to delete data in table, but record in $query in php codeigniter code

Comment: @KH-DP I just updated my code, your are trying "to Removing an item from object in a loop"... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843157/removing-an-item-from-object-in-a-loop

Comment: it's still can't delete. If in normal code maybe work, but it in CodeIgniter

Comment: Using CodeIgniter shouldn't have nothing to do with it...what you could do is instead of 'unset($rows[$key]);' create a new object $rows_new[] = $row;

Answer (score 1):

Do an invert an add it to an new array:

```
$new_result = array();

foreach($query->result() as $row){
    if($row->parent_id != 1){
       $new_result[] = $row;
    }
}
```

After that work with the $new_result object.

ps: wouldn't it be easier to filter the rows in the SQL query?

Comment: i have more than 20 category as menu-item and have three level menu. If i filter it by connect to database mean that: one query to select parent menu-item, then loop more than 20 times for sub menu-item, then loop for child sub menu-item

Comment: Ok, i think you want this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840319/build-a-tree-from-a-flat-array-in-php

Comment: Thank you fccotech for your recursive function